# How do I prevent react scroll event (modal) from being duplicated?

Tags: reactjs

```
function Modal() {
    const [closeModal, setCloseModal] = useState()

    const openModal = () => {
        if (setCloseModal(false)) {
            return
        } else if (window.scrollY >= 1000) {
            setCloseModal(true)
        }
        return closeModal
    }

    useEffect(()=> {
            window.addEventListener('scroll', openModal)
            return () => window.removeEventListener('scroll', openModal)}
        ,[])


    return (
        <>
             <div className='m_background' style={{ display: closeModal ? "flex" : "none" }} >
                 Hello! Everyone~
                 <button className='closeModal' onClick={() => {
                     setCloseModal(false)
                 }}> close?? </button>
             </div>
        </>
    )
}
```

At first, the modal is off, and when I scroll down, the modal turns on.
But even if I press the close button and turn off the modal, when I scroll again, the modal is turned on.
How to prevent duplicate execution?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure why do you have

```
if (setCloseModal(false)) {
        return
    }
```

in your `openModal` handler since `setCloseModal(false)` gives undefined i.e false.
And in general sense, as the event listener is still active on the window (since removeEventListener will only happen once the component unmounts), every time your `window.scrollY >= 1000` logic is satisfied, the modal will be again set to on.
if you only want the modal to be on once per page load, you can try removing the eventListener after the first time your condition to set modal satisfies. i.e  `window.scrollY >= 1000` in your case.
But I would suggest you to refactor your `openModal` handler